# Minecraft Block Harvest Level Restriction

Tags: java, minecraft

I am coding a minecraft mod, and I am trying to make my block drop loot only when mined with a harvest level of 2 or more(iron or above). I set my harvest level to 2 but still can mine it with my fist. Why is this? Here is my code for the block.

```
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.common.ToolType;

public class RubyBlock extends Block {
public RubyBlock(){
 super(Properties.create(Material.IRON)
    .hardnessAndResistance(5.0f,6.0f)
     .sound(SoundType.METAL)
     .harvestLevel(2)


            .harvestTool(ToolType.PICKAXE)






    );

}

}
```

Comment: Hello!  Unfortunately, questions like this aren't a great fit for SO.  We have lots of great programmers who can answer java questions, but a question like this is about the Minecraft API, not java.  You would get much better and faster answers on a Minecraft modding forum.

Comment: As mentioned by Chalie this is best asked on a Minecraft mod forum. But just in case someone can help, which API are you using? I don't see any obvious issue with this code, but how are the RubyBlocks being added to the world?

Comment: They are added through a registry handler.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and after a brief google search, I found this post on the forge forms https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/87845-solved-bug-fixed-harvest-level-just-straight-up-not-working/

Apparently you need to add `.func_235861_h_()` after setting the harvest level and tool to reload with the new information.

```java
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.common.ToolType;

public class RubyBlock extends Block {
  public RubyBlock(){
    super(Properties.create(Material.IRON)
      .hardnessAndResistance(5.0f,6.0f)
      .sound(SoundType.METAL)
      .harvestLevel(2)
      .harvestTool(ToolType.PICKAXE)
      .func_235861_h_()


    );

  }

}
```